# How to write HTTP request for using third party API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, http, curl

## Background

I'm in a small private JavaScript+HTML project and I'm trying to use [HTML PDF API](https://htmlpdfapi.com/). This API provides the process of converting HTML strings to PDF file.
However, being very novice in engineering stuffs, lacking knowledges and experiences around HTTP, Web, API, server side programming, I'm struggling with knowing what to do for achieving my goal.

## Problem

I tried a curl snippet which is shown in [this usage page](https://htmlpdfapi.com/documentation/usage), showing how to get access to the API and generate pdf from html string.

[Generate PDF from HTML string]

```
curl -H 'Authentication: Token <your token>' \
-d 'html=<h1>HTML PDF API is cool!</h1>' \
'https://htmlpdfapi.com/api/v1/pdf' > result.pdf
```

I tried it and it worked on my terminal. But, [the site](https://htmlpdfapi.com/) doesn't show any example for using this in the JavaScript (node.js) code.

So, it seems I have to research the way on my own and the points might be following:

- Understand general HTTP request format and write down the HTTP request which includes the contents written in the curl snippet above.
- Rewrite the HTTP request into JSON format.
- Write the JavaScript (node.js) code for HTTP communication with the API site, and include the request JSON object above.

However, because of my lack of ability, I couldn't find the articles which include the least information for achieving the three milestones above.

Could you show me some good articles or hint?

Any information would be appreciated.

## Progress

I searched and tried to make and send HTTP request to [HTML PDF API](https://htmlpdfapi.com/) using `superagent` with the code below.

```
var request = require('superagent');

request.post('https://htmlpdfapi.com/api/v1/pdf')
   .send({Authentication: "Token <my token>",
          html:"<h1>HTML PDF API is cool!</h1>"
        })
   .end(function(res){
     if (res.ok) {
       console.log(res.body.name);
     } else {
       console.log('error');
       console.log(res);
     }
});
```

However, the result is 401 error like below:

```
Error: Unauthorized
    at Request.callback (C:\Users\myName\node_modules\superagent\lib\node\index.js:883:15)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\myName\node_modules\superagent\lib\node\index.js:1127:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1327:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  status: 401,
  response: <ref *1> Response {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
    _eventsCount: 0,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    res: IncomingMessage {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 4,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      httpVersionMajor: 1,
      httpVersionMinor: 1,
      httpVersion: '1.1',
      complete: true,
      headers: [Object],
      rawHeaders: [Array],
      trailers: {},
      rawTrailers: [],
      aborted: false,
      upgrade: false,
      url: '',
      method: null,
      statusCode: 401,
      statusMessage: 'Unauthorized',
      client: [TLSSocket],
      _consuming: false,
      _dumped: false,
      req: [ClientRequest],
      text: 'Token missing.',
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
    },
    request: Request {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _enableHttp2: false,
      _agent: false,
      _formData: null,
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://htmlpdfapi.com/api/v1/pdf',
      _header: [Object],
      header: [Object],
      writable: true,
      _redirects: 0,
      _maxRedirects: 5,
      cookies: '',
      qs: {},
      _query: [],
      qsRaw: [],
      _redirectList: [],
      _streamRequest: false,
      _data: [Object],
      req: [ClientRequest],
      protocol: 'https:',
      host: 'htmlpdfapi.com',
      _endCalled: true,
      _callback: [Function (anonymous)],
      res: [IncomingMessage],
      _resBuffered: true,
      response: [Circular *1],
      called: true,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    req: ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 3,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: false,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: false,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      _contentLength: 99,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      _header: 'POST /api/v1/pdf HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Host: htmlpdfapi.com\r\n' +
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n' +
        'Content-Type: application/json\r\n' +
        'Content-Length: 99\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'POST',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      path: '/api/v1/pdf',
      _ended: true,
      res: [IncomingMessage],
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'htmlpdfapi.com',
      protocol: 'https:',
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
    },
    text: 'Token missing.',
    body: {},
    files: undefined,
    buffered: true,
    headers: {
      server: 'nginx',
      date: 'Mon, 31 May 2021 09:36:23 GMT',
      'content-type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',
      'content-length': '14',
      connection: 'close',
      'x-powered-by': 'Express',
      etag: 'W/"e-6MRs7J3ixq1Oxcy3SHuOU96JCDo"'
    },
    header: {
      server: 'nginx',
      date: 'Mon, 31 May 2021 09:36:23 GMT',
      'content-type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',
      'content-length': '14',
      connection: 'close',
      'x-powered-by': 'Express',
      etag: 'W/"e-6MRs7J3ixq1Oxcy3SHuOU96JCDo"'
    },
    statusCode: 401,
    status: 401,
    statusType: 4,
    info: false,
    ok: false,
    redirect: false,
    clientError: true,
    serverError: false,
    error: Error: cannot POST /api/v1/pdf (401)
        at Response.toError (C:\Users\myName\node_modules\superagent\lib\node\response.js:98:13)
        at ResponseBase._setStatusProperties (C:\Users\myName\node_modules\superagent\lib\response-base.js:119:48)
        at new Response (C:\Users\myName\node_modules\superagent\lib\node\response.js:44:8)
        at Request._emitResponse (C:\Users\myName\node_modules\superagent\lib\node\index.js:930:18)
        at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\myName\node_modules\superagent\lib\node\index.js:1127:42)
        at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
        at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1327:12)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
      status: 401,
      text: 'Token missing.',
      method: 'POST',
      path: '/api/v1/pdf'
    },
    created: false,
    accepted: false,
    noContent: false,
    badRequest: false,
    unauthorized: true,
    notAcceptable: false,
    forbidden: false,
    notFound: false,
    unprocessableEntity: false,
    type: 'text/plain',
    charset: 'utf-8',
    links: {},
    setEncoding: [Function: bound ],
    redirects: [],
    pipe: [Function (anonymous)],
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  }
}
```

What is wrong? Any information would be appreciated.

Comment: When I google "node api request", this is the first result for me: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/http-requests-in-node-js.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't looked at what cURL is doing closely enough.

> ```
> curl -H 'Authentication: Token <your token>' \
> -d 'html=<h1>HTML PDF API is cool!</h1>' \
> 'https://htmlpdfapi.com/api/v1/pdf' > result.pdf
> ```

`-H` is a **header** which you add to superagent using [the `set` method](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#setting-header-fields).

`-d` is the request body, which is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoded, not JSON encoded. So, [as per the docs](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#post--put-requests) you need to pass strings and not an object.

```
request.post('https://htmlpdfapi.com/api/v1/pdf')
    .set('Authentication', 'Token <your token>')
    .send('html=<h1>HTML PDF API is cool!</h1>')
    .then(callback, errorCallback);
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand JSON cannot be used in this case. However, I tried your snippet, but it returns "callback is not defined". Do you know what is happening?

Comment: You didn't define the `callback` function which is passed as the first argument to `then` on the last line of the example.

Comment: Thank you. I set callback and errorCallback on my own, and it worked.